# How does this application make 3d images?

Tags: 3d, android-camera, virtual-reality

I have seen the android application 'reality hacker vr'.
It makes the picture from camera be vr image.
 I think that it has to estimate the distance of each pixel by using some algorothms to make vr image, since smartphone camera can't measure distance of each pixel.
 but, I don't know to do this. Is there any method to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description (and plausibility) it takes the same camera image and displays it for both eyes. The images have to be slightly offset for each eye for them to converge. This will not generate a 3D effect, though.